# Wording of infinitesimal

Tags: calculus

I'm intending to use the following math metaphor, but am not sure it is worded correctly: "Just as an infinitesimal derivative of the second order may be infinitely *smaller* than an infinitesimal of the first order, so could our feelings in 2018 be magnitudes worse."

Does that make sense, or is it off significantly or just somewhat?

I do understand that "infinitesimal" could be dated, but am I using it correctly here as a metaphor in a way that would have been OK in its heyday?

Thank you.

Comment: I think what you mean is, in the standard sense, referring to a second order Taylor term vs. a first order Taylor term, where close enough to the point of expansion the first is far smaller than the second. But that's not a derivative. There also is no way to make sense of the universal "order" of an infinitesimal; given an infinitesimal $dx$, $dx^2$ is far smaller than $dx$, but there isn't a way to say that $dx$ was "first order" except perhaps that it is "first order in itself" which is somewhat circular. Overall I think this is just unnecessarily flowery for your purpose.

Comment: Because of the word *derivative*, this makes no sense to me. You also seem to imply that the current feelings are already a disgrace. If this is intended to a lambda audience, they'll just miss the meaning.

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: "... he who can digest a second or third fluxion, a second or third differential, need not, methinks, be squeamish about any point in divinity." -- George Berkeley

Comment: There are problems (as in other comments) with the literal sense of what you're saying, but it is also possible to tweak it to make sense. Nevertheless, it might be better to just be more down-to-earth, given your apparent prior experience, intended audience, and so on.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Perhaps I could start with this: "Just as an infinitesimal of second-order smallness is infinitely smaller than an infinitesimal of first-order smallness, . . ." The "second-order smallness" could, for example, be something vanishing much more rapidly because it is diminishing in each of two dimensions, compared to something diminishing in one dimension only. Of course, I may not understand infinitesimals in general, so this new wording could still be a problem.

Comment: Here is the entire metaphor: "Just as an infinitesimal of second-order smallness can become infinitely smaller than an infinitesimal of first-order smallness, so to in reverse fashion could our considerable troubles become infinitely greater in 2018."

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed use of the words "infinitesimal", "derivative", "order" and "magnitudes" is drivel. To use a term as part of a metaphor places a very strong obligation on you to understand that term. (In your proposed statement, "magnitudes" is particularly bad: it implies a definite quantitive estimate that you definitely don't have.)